# why doesn't debugging with eclipse work?

Tags: python, eclipse, python-2.7, debugging

I am using eclipse - Neon Release (4.6.0) and python 2.7.
Every time I run the debugger I get the message below and I can't figure out what is the problem.
What is missing here?

> 'Launcing start_debugger.py' has encountered a problem. Varaible
>   refernces nin-existent resource:
>   ${workspace_loc:automation/debugger_test.py}

Comment: I don't think is a question for SO (where code s fixed). I would suggest deleting eclipse and downloading again as a start - seems your workspace is corrupt.

Comment: I tried it but it didn't work,do you know any forum which is suitable to the question?@kabanus

Comment: Definitely, the [eclipse forums](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/f/89/). The new comer page has several suggestions and faqs before asking your question. Good luck.